# Encoding elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding

I would like to encode contents of elements using jQuery but I can't find a function which does this automatically, so I'm trying to create a function which does this content by content.

For example if I have the following HTML element:

```
<div>
    text&
    <p class="foo">barbaz8798++xyzzy</p>
    <span>1<5</span>
</div>
```

The desired output would be:

```
<div>
    text%26
    <p class="foo">barbaz8798%2B%2Bxyzzy</p>
    <span>1%3C5</span>
</div>
```

I need to encode only the contents of those elements. How can I achieve this?

One approach which came to my mind is to select the elements by wrapping everything into a wrapper and then calling `wrapper.find("*")` and then replace their text with `element.text(encodeURIComponent(element.text()))`, but isn't there a better way, please?

Comment: you want to work on only text nodes, else you'll escape the markup itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over the contents of the container element(`div` in your sample) the change the contents of all text nodes

```js
//need to use a more specific selector for the div
$('div').find('*').addBack().contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    this.nodeValue = encodeURIComponent(this.nodeValue.trim());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  text&
  <p class="foo">barbaz8798++xyzzy</p>
  <span>1<5</span>
</div>
```